# Parse "form action" property out of web page in R

Tags: html, r, xml

I am trying to follow the [National Library of Medicine's new ticket-based authentication](https://documentation.uts.nlm.nih.gov/rest/authentication.html).

I have `POST`ed my API key:

```
tgt <-
  POST(
    url = "https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/v1/api-key", encode = "form",
    body = list("apikey" = "SECRET")
  )

tgt.page <- read_html(rawToChar(tgt$content))
```

and I got a response in roughly this format:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>201 The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created</title></head>
<body><h1>TGT Created</h1>
<form action="https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-36471-aYqNLN2rFIJPXKzxwdTNC5ZT7z3B3cTAKfSc5ndHQcUxeaDOLN-cas" method="POST">Service:<input type="text" name="service" value="">
<br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
</body>
</html>

<!--take the 'action' attribute of the form element and re-use it as your URI to get a service ticket as in call #2 above.-->
```

Now I have to extract the Ticket Granting Ticket from the "form action". My reading suggests that `rvest::html_nodes` might be a reasonable choice here too. I have extracted the form, but don't know how to get the action property (?) other than using a substring approach.

```
html_nodes(x = tgt.page, xpath = "//form")
```

Will I also have to import `XML` or `xml2` and use one of their functions?

Answer (score 0):

This extracts the "action" attribute:

```
tgt <-
  html_attr(html_nodes(x = tgt.page, xpath = "//form"), "action")
```

then a service ticket can be obtained like

```
st.req <-
  POST(
    url = tgt, encode = "form",
    body = list("service" = "http://umlsks.nlm.nih.gov")
  )

st <- rawToChar(st.req$content)
```